# How to create arrays which are subgroups of larger parent array based upon values of chosen column in parent array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to Python and programming in general. I need to organize a large array of raw data to plot.
The data table has 3 columns: device ID , voltage , current .
The first column has many repeated elements because each 'device ID' has many voltages and currents measured, so there's only a fraction of the rows with unique 'device ID'.
My goal is to plot each device ID in a separate series.
Now, in my mind, I need to separate the array into smaller arrays to use typical plotting commands of matplotlib.
How can I tell python to figure out where in the device ID column does new value appear and either put it into a new array?

I've played around with numpy.unique , but I am now thinking I need for loop to check each row and compare it to previous row, something like:

```py
for row a in Device ID column:
    is row n = n-1?
    if true then continue populating new array with all columns for this row
    if false then start new array with all columns for this row
```

All I've really accomplished is sorting the big array by the device ID column, since I believe it is first step to using the for loop approach

## sort the data by Dev ID (2nd column in raw data)

```py
data_sorted_bydev_id = data[ data[:,1].argsort() ]
```

Just looking for advice if the 'for loop' approach is best way to go from here.

Comment: Pandas dataframe [1] is a great tool to help with tabular data like you've mentioned.  There are a lot of great tutorials on the interwebs to help you get started and familiar with how pandas works.  It is built on numpy so that should make an easy transition.
  [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks, I will start to learn Pandas, so you're saying I shouldn't need a 'for loop' for this operation?

Comment: Yeah, typically there is a way to do just about anything you want in pandas without having to use a `for loop`.  Sorry I don't have an example for this particular use case.